# How do I create a second image instead of populating as a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I've got the code below.  I was using it to use 1 image and use the 'rel' and 'title' tags to populate words to go along with the actual image.  This creating a banner like system that used text instead of all images.  Now, what I want to do is use the 'rel' tag to populate an image; however, don't know how to modify this javascript code to do this.

```
<img title="This is a title that will appear as text above the image" rel="image1" alt="SEO Image 1" src="../images/backdrop2.png">
```

as you can see, rel is equal to image1...so what it needs to do is use this to make...

```
<img class="something" src="images/image1.png">
```

All its doing is using the word that is in 'rel' to fill in that 1 spot and it automatically fills in the rest in the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function( $ ){

    var efx  = "fade", // "slide" || "fade"
            animationTime = 600,
            pauseTime = 4000,
      $gal = $("#images_holder"),
        $mov = $("#moving_part"),
        $sli = $mov.find("> div"),
        $btn = $("#prev, #next"),
            $dsc = $("#description"),
            $wrd = $("#word"),
            w = $gal.width(),
            n = $sli.length,
            c = 0,  // Counter // Start index
            itv;    // Interval


    // SETUP (fade or slide?)
    $mov.width(w*n);
    if(efx==="fade") $sli.css({position:"absolute", left:0}).fadeOut(0).eq(c).fadeIn(0);

    function populateWord() {
        $wrd.text( $sli.eq(c).find("img").attr("rel") );
    }   

    function populateDescription() {
        $dsc.text( $sli.eq(c).find("img").attr("title") );
    }

    function anim() {
        c = c<0 ? n-1 : c%n; // loop-back if exceedds
        populateDescription();
        populateWord();
        if (efx==="fade") {
            $sli.fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeIn(animationTime);
        }else if(efx==="slide") {
            $mov.stop().animate({left: -c*w});
        }
    }

    function auto() {
        itv = setInterval(function(){
           ++c;
           anim();
        }, pauseTime);
    }

    function pause() {
        return clearInterval( itv );
    }

  $gal.hover(pause, auto);

    $btn.on("click", function(){
        c = this.id==="next" ? ++c : --c;
        anim();
    });


    populateDescription();
    populateWord();
    auto();

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function populateWord() {
    var src = 'images/'+$sli.eq(c).find("img").attr("rel")+'.png';
    $wrd.html('<img class="something" src="'+src+'">');
}
```

Comment: You have a typo; however, it did work once I fixed it.  Extra ) after "rel"  `var src = 'images/'+$sli.eq(c).find("img").attr("rel")+'.png';`

Comment: right, during refactoring the code extra `)` got placed, corrected now.

Comment: Really quick: Do you see why the image is fading but the #word image that was just made AND the text from "title" aren't fading.  They are just changing.

Comment: actually I cant as all the necessary code for visualization is not here. Can you create a fiddle

Comment: i tried; however, the fiddles aren't treating the code correct at all, for some reason.  So I was unable to get it to work.

Comment: looking into the link you provided

Comment: `$sli.fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeIn(animationTime);` change to 
`$sli.add('#description').add('#img2').fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeIn(animationTime);`

Comment: that added a syntax error in my document and the entire script stopped working

Comment: ok.. you might have used $sli other places, then do this.
`$('#description' , '#img2').fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeI‌​n(animationTime);` After the line `$sli.fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeIn(animationTime);`

Comment: that also broke script :/

Comment: keep the code and send me the link of your site again, this should not break the code at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83026/discussion-between-vinayakj-and-kdj).

Comment: when you get a chance, could you check out the chat again.